# How would you explain the limiting behavior when $t$ is large in the multi-variable function $w(x,t)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Here is $w(x,t)$: $$w(x,t)=1+2t+\pi\cos(3\pi t)\cos(3\pi x)-2\sin(t)-7\cos(5\pi t)\cos(5\pi x).$$

So far I know tht when $t$ is large, the limit does not exist as $t$ goes to infinity because the limit as $t$ goes to infinity, $\cos(3\pi t)$ diverges and $\cos(5\pi t)$ diverges, and $2t=\infty$.

Comment: You seem to have some understanding of the limiting behavior of the individual terms. Can you combine that to describe the limiting behavior of $w(x,t)$?

Comment: When t is large in w(x,t), then the limit as t approaches infinity will not exist and thus w(x,t) will diverge. Would this be correct?

Comment: Depends on your class/whoever is grading your assignment, but you may need to be more specific than “will not exist” and “diverge”.

Comment: Hint: when $t$ is very large, can you say (a) that $w(x,t)$ will be very large, (b) that $w(x,t)$ will oscillate between very large and very small values, or (c) nothing about what $w(x,t)$ will be?

Comment: I can say (b) that w(x,t) will oscillate between very large and very small values because let's say you have sin(at) as t goes to infinity and cos(at) as t goes  to infinity. Then the limit does not exist as they oscillate between -1 and 1 as the limit t approaches infinity.  So in this case,it would make sense that w(x,t) will oscillate between very large and very small values.

Comment: What’s the largest/smallest $w(x,t)$ can be when $t=1,000$? $t=1,000,000$?